# Vertical alignment for selected headers in table with some multi-column headers

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

In a table containing some header columns spanning across multiple columns, I would like to be able to vertically align remaining header columns. This is shown in the example below *Note 1* and *Note 2* text should be on the level of a line break between *System A* - *Level 1* *Level 2*.

[image]

## Code

```
% vim:ft=tex:

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,
          sectionpage=progressbar,
      subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme

% Packages
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Proper table lines
\usepackage{makecell}       % Break long text in cells


% Title page
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\date{August 2018}
\author{Author Name}

% Main document
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{frame}{Header}
      \begin{center}
          \begin{tabular}{llllll} 
              \toprule
              \multicolumn{2}{c}{System~A} & Note 1 & Note 2& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Outcomes} \\
              Level 1 & Level 2 &  & & Something & Something \\ 
              \midrule
              \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
  \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

it is done by use of the `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,
          sectionpage=progressbar,
      subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme

% Packages
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Proper table lines
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}       % Break long text in cells


% Title page
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\date{August 2018}
\author{Author Name}

% Main document
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{frame}{Header}
      \begin{center}
          \begin{tabular}{llllll}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{System~A}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{Note1}
            &   \multirow{2}{*}{Note2}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Outcomes}                    \\
      Level 1   & Level 2   &   &   & Something     & Something     \\
      \midrule
      \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

note: the `multirow` packages is intended to make "multi row cells", i.e. cells  which merges cells in the defined number of rows (actually number of text lines in adjacent cells). for more details see the package documentation. it is part of your latex installation or you can find on CTAN archive, for example [here](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf).

Comment: Yes, could you explain the mechanics behind it?

Comment: see edited answer.